# How to autoload a site through a php file?

Tags: php, redirect

Is there a way to use a php file to automatically load a website.

I have a new version of my website, but I want to keep the current version live (with its current domain). I would just like to direct clients/customers to preview the new version but still be able to go to the current site.

For example: They would go to the current site by visiting www.currentsite.com. And to visit the new version they would visit www.currentsite.com/newversion

Both sites are subfolders within the root of my hosting account. How do I achieve this?

Thanks for any help on this question.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Just place one site in one folder, and the other in another? And I don't understand what this has to do with autoloading?

Comment: Seems like you just need to copy the new site into that directory to me. Is there a problem with that?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for. They can visit either one of the URLs, presumably following a link from one to the other. What's missing here? What do you need to be automated?

Comment: @Pekka, @Tim: Theres no problem, just a preference. I could just give the direct link to the new version, but its about presentation.

Comment: @madmik3: I would have to change file references to the new folder. I don't want to copy the new site to the current folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to take a look at [.htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) files:

Assuming your current website is located in `/home/user/public_html/current` and your new website is in `/home/user/public_html/new`, you could set up something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Rewrite every uri that does not start with /newversion/ to the current website
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/newversion/?(.*)$
RewriteRule (.+) /current/$1 [NC,L]

# Rewrite everything else to /new
RewriteRule (.+) /new/$1 [NC,L]
```

***Judging from your post and the fact that you are mentioning multiple folders in a hosting account, there is a pretty good chance you already have something like this setup for your current website.***

Take a look in your root folder and see if there is a `.htaccess` file and start editing away.

Comment: Thanks a lot Aron, I'll definitely look into this!

Comment: Aron, I tried to implement this, but not sure if Im doing it right (guess not, cause Im getting an error). The current site has its own domain, and the new version has a direct url to its folder. Using your example, I left "newversion" the same (I would like this name to link to the new version). Where it says "current," I gave it the name of the current site's folder in the root. And where it says "new," I gave it the name of the actual folder of the newversion site within the root...Some help please

Comment: You will need to post more details about this: exact folder structure (preferably in the OP displayed in a tree structure), the exact contents of your .htaccess file and where it is located, and possibly output from your apache error log. Please remember that the above is just a quick example which probably needs some altering to work.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a PHP-only solution, you can put an `index.php` or simmilar file at the root folder of the domain containing:

```
<?php

header("Location: http://www.currentsite.com/current");

?>
```

That would enable a redirection from http://www.currentsite.com/ to http://www.currentsite.com/current. The drawback is that you'd have to stick with "current" in your path, so I'd go for the more elegant .htaccess solution.

**EDIT**

Oh, and if you already have an .htaccess file in the root folder doing similar rewriting tasks, chances are this approach won't work as `index.php` won't ever be reached. You'd better check for that first.

Answer (score 1):

Or create a simple index.html file in the "/newversion" directory with an iframe.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<body>
<iframe src="/" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do not ever suggest the use of frames.

Comment: @Peeter: As I read it it's something temporary to display a new version of the site to a customer. That's perfectly ok to do so.